# add a track multiple times to different peers

Tags: webrtc

I have a server that connects through WebRTC to several peers.
Each new peer connected to the server will receive the other peers video tracks.
For example:

- PeerA connects to PeerServer and successfully negotiate.
- PeerB connects to PeerServer and successfully negotiate.
- Both PeerA and PeerB has their tracks working on the server.
- PeerServer get the videoTrack from PeerA and adds (addTrack) to the PeerB.
- PeerServer get the videoTrack from PeerB and adds (addTrack) to the PeerA.

No exception occurs, but PeerA doesn't receive the track of PeerB from the server and neither PeerB receive PeerAs Track from the server.

Is this possible at all?

Browser compatibility is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

What server are you using? My guess is that re-negotation is failing OR not happening at all.

`chrome://webrtc-internals` will show the signaling state transitions that are happening.

If you need a working example of a server that supports re-negotation you can try [play-from-disk-renegotation](https://github.com/pion/webrtc/tree/master/examples/play-from-disk-renegotation) it shows add/removing a track from a PeerConnection at runtime.